# put designer window in background

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

This is annoying ... In Delphi 7 when you clicked on the code window the form would automatically hide. Now it stays on top. I have to minimize it to remove it from focus. Are there any settings that correct this behaviour ? Also I must play hide and seek with component pallete on the right. I have it open but soon as I try and click on the scroll bar to try and search for my components I get everything replaced by Delphi projects etc. Then I must click inside the form for the component pallete to come back again. Annoying... Any way to disable this ?

Comment: -1 this is a rant. No doubt there are some good questions here but a user with your rep should know by now how to ask questions.

Comment: not a rant ... just trying to improve my IDE practicality ... I never actually digged into the "options" so thats why I am asking. To save me some time...

Comment: It's a rant not a question. Anyway, press F12 to toggle between designer and code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can disable the embedded designer in order which the switch between the form and the code will be like the Delphi 7 IDE.

`Tools-> Options -> Environment Options -> Vcl Designer -> Embedded designer (uncheck)`

Also you can take a look to the Simon Stuart plugin [RADSplit](http://www.simonjstuart.com/delphi-stuff/radsplit/)

Now for the `component palette` part, this windows change depending of the current active form , so if you active window is the form designer the Tool palette show the components else show the Delphi projects menu. Anyway Delphi XE2 includes the classic palette component which always show the components in top toolbar even if you are in the source code view.

[image]

Comment: I have disabled the embedded designer already but still my window stays on top even if I click the code in the background. In Delphi 7 it used to toggle automatically. The palette I have on my right side and  not like the one above. It seems I have to pin it to stay where it is. But when I click inside (code) then my pallete changes again back to delphi Projects etc... What I would like is most is to be able to toggle the form during design time with just mouse click... I hate pressing F12 constantly ...

Comment: This RadSplit tool looks promising (beta thou) ... if all fail, I will try and use it. ;) In D7 you juste clicked or on code or on form and begun editing.You had everything on screen. Now to edit code I must drag away or minimize my form. Playing hide and seek with components palette  is tiring . I am wondering, is this default behaviour or can I do something about it ?

Comment: Interesting... I enabled embedded designer once more,restarted the ide. Then Once more I disabled it and again restarted the IDE and now the damn thing works. Finally... It seems something got stuck somewhere... Thank you RRUZ ...It seems you have to remove the default layout as well .... selected it to none and my palette stoped playing games with me ...